# Symfony-cli web server after upgrade to version 5.8.13

Tags: symfony-cli

Today I upgraded Symfony-cli to version 5.8.13 with brew. In my project, I start a new web server: `Symfony-cli server:start`

After that I open my browser to 127.0.0.1:8000, but my web server Symfony crashes

```
2024/03/23 10:19:36 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:49889: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0
goroutine 35 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1()
    net/http/server.go:1898 +0xbe
panic({0x102440c0?, 0xc00038e120?})
    runtime/panic.go:770 +0x132
github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/envs.(*Local).webServer(0xc000430660)
    github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/envs/local.go:262 +0x5b8
github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/envs.(*Local).Extra(0xc000430660)
    github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/envs/local.go:210 +0x38f
github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/envs.AsMap({0x10297800, 0xc000430660})
    github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/envs/envs.go:86 +0x258
github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/local/php.(*Server).generateEnv(0xc000177340, 0xc00037e120)
    github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/local/php/envs.go:76 +0x9f8
github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/local/php.(*Server).Serve(0xc000177340, {0x10294898, 0xc000404000}, 0xc00037e120, 0xc000430600)
    github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/local/php/php_server.go:209 +0x7f
github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/local/http.(*Server).Handler(0xc000385a00, {0x10294898, 0xc000404000}, 0xc00037e120)
    github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/local/http/http.go:244 +0x538
github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/local/http.(*Server).ProxyHandler(0xc000385a00, {0x10294448, 0xc0001761c0}, 0xc00037e120)
    github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/local/http/http.go:187 +0x2d8
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xfa15cb9?, {0x10294448?, 0xc0001761c0?}, 0xc0003c3b68?)
    net/http/server.go:2166 +0x29
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP({0xc0004300f0?}, {0x10294448?, 0xc0001761c0?}, 0x6?)
    net/http/server.go:3137 +0x8e
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc000488090, {0x102956f0, 0xc0003400f0})
    net/http/server.go:2039 +0x5e8
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve in goroutine 54
    net/http/server.go:3285 +0x4b4
```

I tested on another machine and I have the same problem.

Comment: I've just upgraded my version to try, and got the same. https://github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/issues/456

Comment: 5.8.14 has been released with the problem code reverted.

Answer (score 0):

Type these commands:

- `scoop uninstall symfony-cli` (uninstall all symfony-cli versions)
- `scoop install symfony-cli@5.8.12` (installation of functional update 5.8.12 of symfony cli)